# The Fokker-Planck equation and potential

Tags: potential, schroedinger-equation, stochastic-processes

Anybody know the [Fokker-Planck equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fokker%E2%80%93Planck_equation) with a potential term in the front?

$$\frac{\partial P}{\partial t}=\left[V(x)-\partial A+\frac{1}{2}\partial B\partial B\right]P.$$

The above is the form of the Fokker-Planck equation.
A is the drift and B is given by $$B=\sqrt(D)$$
D is the diffusion term.

- What is the meaning of the potential?
- Is there any connection between the Fokker-Planck equation and Schrodinger equation of motion?

Comment: Did you check [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fokker%E2%80%93Planck_equation#Solution)?